# Wordpress - Descargar pagina (sin plugins)

Tags: wordpress

He creado una pagina web muy sencilla en wordpress, no esta en ningún hosting, esta en un "dominio.wordpress.com", quiero descargar la pagina para poder instalarla en mi hosting local pero no encuentro ninguna forma. Solamente veo que las descargan con plugins y en mi plan no estan habilitados los plugins. Hay alguna forma de descargarla o tengo que pagar para que lo haga un plugins?

Comment: fijate si tenes habilitada la opción exportar 
https://wordpress.com/es/support/export/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lastimosamente eso no es posible, Wordpress.com bloquea la instalación de plugins almenos que tengas un plan y tampoco puedes ingresar por ftp ya que este también esta bloqueado y solo se puede acceder con dicho plan, por lo que no existe forma de copiar tu sitio de forma manual o con plugins, lo mas cercano es importar todos los archivos multimedia y el contenido del sitio con la herramienta "Importar" dentro del administrador en wordpress.com pero es lo mas cercano a eso.

La solución es volver a crear todo el sitio esta vez con wordpress.org en local usando como referencia lo que ya habías creado en wordpress.com e importando lo que el sitio te deja importar o bien, pagar por un plan premium.